# Is updating states before an action, such as transfers, a flat-out rule to follow to avoid reentrancy? Are there scenarios to not follow this rule?

Tags: solidity, reentrant-attacks

I understand that many websites advocate that the best practice is to always place any updating of states before the actual action (such as a transfer) to prevent reentracy problems. But is this a flat-out rule that applies to all scenarios?

As an example below, I have a contract that lets anyone `deposit` their tokens and the contract updates their `balances` in a state. In the `withdraw` function, I agree that updating the `balances` state must be done before `transfer()` function is called. Otherwise, a bad actor can drain the entire balances.

```
contract MyDepositContract {


    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) internal balances;

    function deposit(address token, uint amount) external {
        uint balance = IERC20(token).balanceOf(msg.sender);
        require(balance >= amount, "insufficient balance");

        // Should updating the balances state be here?
        balances[msg.sender][token] += amount;

        IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);

        // Or is updating the balances state better to be here?
        // balances[msg.sender][token] += amount;
    }

    function withdraw(address token, uint amount) external {
        uint balance = balances[msg.sender][token];
        require(balance >= amount, "balance is lesser than amount");
        
        // I agree with updating the balances state here, perfect, I understand.
        balances[msg.sender][token] -= amount;

        IERC20(token).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
    }
}
```

However, in the `deposit()` function, should the updating of `balances` state also be done before the `transferFrom()` function? Let's say if followed the rule and updated the `balances` state before the `transferFrom` function. I could imagine if the `token` address has a tiny bit of malicious or buggy code in it, he could initiate a reentrancy and to increase the balance a few times before eventually calling the `withdraw()` function, draining the balances. He could do this before the `balances` state was updated *before* the actual `transferFrom` had taken place.

On the other hand, if the `balances` were updated *after* `transferFrom` was called, a bad actor wouldn't benefit from a reentrancy because there isn't any changes to the states yet that he could abuse.

Coming back to my question, is the rule that updating of states be done before the actual transfer or an action always true? In my example, are my thoughts correct? Did I miss something in my thought process? Otherwise, where should `balances` be *best* updated in the `deposit` function - before or still after the transfer - and why?

Comment: It is the Check-Effect-Interaction pattern. Usually it is used when the interaction is against an untrusted contract. It is just a recomendation you don't have to follow it blindly, apply your own judgement. In this particualr case I'd call `transfeFrom` first and skip the balance checking. If you can't trust the token contract then it is pointless to make any check. I'd assume that `transferFrom` works as expected.